# NSButtonCell in NSTableView: click handling

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, click, nstableview, nsbuttoncell

I set `NSButtonCell` as a cell type in a `Table Column` in my `NSTableView`.
I implemented an `IBAction` method, but I can't wire it with `NSButtonCell` in IB - the wire don't want to highlight a button from `NSTableView`.

How to connect a method with `NSButtonCell`? Or maybe there'se another way to handle its click event?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean IB that shipped with Xcode 3.x?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to wire up a connection from the cell by control+dragging to any object in your NIB. Just make sure the cell is actually selected, and that your action is defined as an `IBAction` in the object's header file. In your action method you can determine which row was selected by calling `[tableView clickedRow]`.

Edit: Here's a demonstration. **Make sure you click at least four times on the check box to get it selected, hold down the control key and drag from the cell to your object.**

[image]

Comment: I need to wire a `NSButtonCell` with `IBAction` method. If I select `NSButtonCell` and then make right-click on my CustomClass object to see `Received Actions` list, the selection of `NSButtonCell` disappears. If I try to wire from NSButtonCell's `Received Actions` list - where I can find `IBAction` method to bring a wire to it?

Comment: I've added an image to make it clear. You need to control drag *from* the cell onto the receiving object.

Comment: All rigth now!Previously I tryed to bring a wire from cell's `performClick` event in `Received Action` list, not from the cell object itself. Thanks for showing a patience in answering stupid question :)

Comment: Thanks for the part about clicking at least four times! On a side note, in case anyone else was also confused, the reason you can call `[tableView clickedRow]` is because the `NSTableView` is the sender of the action, **not** the `NSButton`.

Comment: Quick note: you can shift-control- (or right-) click on a control to get a list of all the controls at that point (z-order: top-down) and then select the control you want from that list.