# Is an created NSButtonCell unique?

Tags: objective-c, uniqueidentifier, nsbuttoncell

So, is the button identifiable?

I need to identify a cell-botton (`Button Cell`) in a`NSTableView` in order to detect if it was pressed already. The table can always change by user input. My bright idea is if a created button (button cell) were unique it would be identifiable. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells are a little different from full-fledged controls. `NSTableView` reuses a single cell for all the rows of a column. When `NSTableView` draws a row, or when it handles user input, it configures the cell for the row/column in question.

It sounds like in your case you have an `NSButtonCell` and you want to know which row was clicked. You can determine which row was clicked by checking the table view's `clickedRow` property in the button cell's action method. [The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522965/nsbuttoncell-in-nstableview-click-handling) explains how to do this.

Comment: Yes it is an `NSButtonCell`. The `clickedRow` method work for me. But am I right that the number of a specific row will change with deleting/adding rows above?

Comment: That's correct. What I would do is go back to the table's data source and use the row index to fetch the object that the row represents. That should give you the data you need to handle the button click.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as long as these buttons are subclasses of UIView, which UIButtons are, then you can use the tag field to carry a numeric information. Set the button.tag in celForRowAtIndexPath to indexPath.row and you can fetch the tag within the IBAction method that the button should inovke when pressed.

Comment: Hallo Hermann, danke for the answer. The cell buttons are subclasses of `NSButtonCell` class (it's for osx). Would you have a code snippet how to use the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to create the tag?

Comment: Apologies. I overlooked that it was related to the OS-X framework. Obviously I did not really read it and thought it was related to iOS. No, I cannot help with OS-X.

Comment: Glad you got an answer. Tschüs :)